# Add delay to SKEmitter or SKReference to Scene editor

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene, skemitternode, skreferencenode

I'm trying to sempificate some animation with scene kit.
I want to achieve to have an `SKEmitter` to the scene after some delay.
The `SKEmitter` has a limitated number of spawn emitter, so it is during just 1 second, but I want this animation after 2 secon of other animation.
I can achieve this with code, but I would lear some semplification of Scene editor also if is a not mature tool (my opinion).
Any idea?

Comment: You can add actions via the scene builder, perhaps you can use them in a a way to achieve the desired affect

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the problem is that the SKEmitter start at T0, the only action I can apply is a fade in, but not wait time.

Comment: Yeah no wait actions in action editor :)

Comment: Yeah the only solution I could come up with is if you were working with GameplayKit,  then you can add components to do what you are asking.  Unfortunately I could not find any other way since you can't use custom classes on emitters.

Comment: @Whirlwind wait is actually used when you have gaps in your timeline,  there is no way to spawn a node at 2 minutes or pause/unpause :'(

Comment: I had that in mind but still there is not thing like runBlock so as you said, you cant do many things you can do in code, ans functionality is limited... @Knight0fDragon

Comment: Simone,  only thing I can think of which is crazy is to do a referenceNode to a new SKS file, this way you could custom class the new sks and define behavior of a child emitter added to it in that way.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon this sounds like not easiest with versus to add skemitter by code after 1 second... I'm using a sks to animate a bat flying, the directions are not regular. Maybe the only way is to create the actions in sks to see directly the effect and copy the movement in the code of custom class.

Comment: @SimonePistecchia, I would definitely look into doing GamePlayKit then,  the scenebuilder works better when you do components.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon with GameplayKit the editor is different? interessing... unfortunately in this case I've not implemented Gameplay kit

Comment: believe it or not it is exactly the same lol, it just let's you run code via the components, and it is not a lot of work to convert your project over to support GameplayKit

Comment: if you get time, check out the wwdc video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-q4oh7B3qw  it could help solve your problem